# android:text= "SomeText: " doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having some textViews in my activity. I am connecting to a server and fetching some data from database and getting a JSON response and loading the data into my activity and setting the textview text with data fetched from server. Everything works fine. Now the problem is that I want to add some default text in the textview. Right now I only have the author name in the textview and it appears as normal but I want that it should appear like `Author: Dennis`  I have tried to use android:text= "Author: " for author textview but it doesnt work. let me know how can I do this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:text="@string/author"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

and here is my code where I set the text.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] {TITLE, AUTHOR},
                        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.author });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

/Dennis

Comment: can you provide some part of relevant code,xml and also logcat for more help.

Comment: String name="Denis";
textview.setText("Author :"+name);

Comment: my activity is a listactivity and this textview is in layout which I add in the listview. I know I can use textview.setText("Author :"+name); but in my case i am not setting the text as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set the text do:

```
textview.setText(textview.getText() + " " + serverresponsestring);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @rotem. I know we can set text as you described but I am not setting it directly. my textview is part of layout which I am setting in listview. So I am not calling set function to set the text in textview. I have described above how i am setting it.

Comment: actually you do set the text programmatically - the simpleAdapter that you use does that. you can add the text "Author: " to every item in your Strings array before you send it to the adapter, or you can write your own adapter.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It will take some extra time to write my own adapter because I have to read about it how to write adapters for listview. I just concatinate the "Author: " string with Dennis before sending it to adapter. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Author: is being read as a class name. Try writing android:text="Author\\:" and tell me what happens.

The android manual says double slashes escape strings
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2219

Comment: Be sure to let me know what happens.

Comment: Are you using the backslash located below the backspace key and not the one on the question mark key?

Comment: I am using this " \ " backslash. its on the question mark ? key.